# Odoo 10 company branches

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to implement branches of a company in Odoo 10 and have come across "Companies" feature. From what I've understood, these could behave as parent/child companies in Odoo 8 but I'm unable to replicate it in 10, as those settings are removed.

Is there any way to replicate with some addon (which I've searched for, but may have missed) or will it have to be developed?

The primary goal is to have the customers associated to branches, have separate backend users per branch, have independent billing for each branch, but still have accumulative access to all these at parent level as ultimately all the branches belong to the same company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent/child company features is already there in V10
you just need to enable "Multi Companies" feature.

> Settings > users > Technical Settings > multi companies > check it

Note: Technical Settings will only visible in user if 'developer mode' is ON.